# trigger jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, html, jquery-plugins, triggers

I'm using this jQuery plugin: http://gianlucaguarini.com/canvas-experiments/jQuery.BlackAndWhite/.
It basically sets images in black and white, and when you hover the image, it gets colored.

Now I'm wondering if it would be possible to trigger the plugin (color the picture) when hovering something else (some text).

I tried triggering hover() and mouseenter on the element, but that didn't seem to do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried binding the image trigger event to different element and it worked.

I did that:

```
$('elem').on('click', function() {
    $('.imgWrap').eq(0).trigger('mouseenter');
});
```

It worked, it colored the picture, so triggering `mouseleave` will uncolor it again.

You have to find a way to determine which element triggers which image (the `.eq(0)` is just for testing, in a real situation you will need something more specific, otherwise you will affect all images.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, but what i mean is this: the plugin transforms the image when you hover the image. I want to transform the image when hovering something else (like a piece of text)